# insert php code in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make on my page sidebars, where i can put my log in form, partners, profile and etc.
problem is that i cant insert code with included file

```
<?php include "mini_profile.php"; ?>
```

how can i insert codes like that in database and what database type should i use?
Or how can insert that code directly in to file i need?
Thanks for your help.
This is what i use for posting into sidebar:

```
    <?php

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM r_sidebar");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    echo "<div class='right_bar'>";

    echo "<div class='right_bar_title'>";
        echo "<div style='font-weight: bold;'>";
            echo $row['title'];
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

        echo $row['content'];
    echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Generally that is a really bad idea as it is going to make you need to use `eval()` in order to execute the code. It is a REALLY bad idea to execute arbitary code from some external datasource. Not to mention it will likely be a real pain down the line to have to change code in multiple places (i.e. both in file editor and in database) when you want to make changes. This is not to even mention to pain of escaping all of that. I strongly suggest you rethink your approach. and consider using includes with perhaps a DB config to determine which files to include on specific pages.

Comment: Orangepill, if you can't help, don't know how, can't give useful code example - please stop commenting. Hate people like u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save PHP directly as a string in any database, but it's generally best not to.  You have to load the PHP code and evaluate it at run-time which presents a number of different security issues.

It's better to use a templating system or framework (like Smarty, Yii, Zend or Symphony) and create templates that evaluate in data points rather than PHP code.

Comment: @MarcB fair enough but there are good frameworks that allow you to avoid boilerplate and get better separation of presentation and application logic (and which won't open up security issues like what was suggested in the question).

Comment: oh, i see. i taught about that it's not secure and etc.
i just want to make that i can add and delete sidebars, it works great like posting news or something, but cant put there my log in form, i put it in separated file for that i can just include it where i want.
thanks for your answer maybe you can give me some alternative code examples from what i can learn from.
i have like file r_sidebar.php and i want to add from admin panel blocks in it like login form and etc. and way how to delete or update/change them would be nice too.